# Remove the Cancel Link in the twitter App opened using ShareKit framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, sharekit

I want to remove the "cancel and return to the APP" link from the twitter page opened using ShareKit Framework.

When i click on that link it redirects me to the website i entered in the dev.twitter.com. I want to remove that link or atleast close the dialog box of twitter and return to my App.

I have tried and debugged the share kit code and couldn't find any where the code for that particular link.

I know that the Cancel link will take us to the website which we provide in the developer.twitter.com site's WebSite field.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept the cancel request and hide your UIWebView, you can do it in the view controller that contains the UIWebView you are using. Use the delegate function

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

to capture the URL requests. If you search for the string that relates to returning to the app, you can perform any action you want (eg. dismissing the view controller and returning to the app). This can be done using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString* requestURL = request.URL.absoluteString;

    if ([requestURL rangeOfString:@"denied="].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        // DISMISS YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER HERE
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This is of course dependent on the URL returned by twitter which is subject to change, and the string "denied=" could just as easily be replaced by your website URL.

Answer (score 1):

Add a URL scheme in your app, then populate the website address on dev.twitter.com with your new URL scheme (for example "yourapp://twitterauthfail"). This way when your user presses the cancel button they'll be directed back to your app.

Comment: i added the URL scheme in the app's info.plist as 
URL Identifier : com.acme.myappname
URL Scheme : myappname://test.com
Now the problem is in the dev.twitter.com i cannot enter the Website address as "myappname://test.com" because is gives me an error saying NOT A VALID URL FORMAT.
If i append http:// to my URL Scheme then also this is not working.
NOTE: I have written the "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url" method in my apps delegate  file.
Can you please throw some more light on this issue of mine?
Some e.g. would be of great help. txs in advance

Comment: I didn't realise Twitter has limitations like this, sorry. I think the easiest solution would be to place a redirect on your website to your apps URL scheme, i.e., you tell Twitter the website is http://yourwebsite.com/auth and you get your website to rediect that to yourapp://auth.

Comment: i think this might work. i will give it a try and post the result. thanks 4 d follow up !!

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom url schemes that will open your app, but you can't make your app the designated handler for certain domain names so that opening that domain in Safari will launch your app automatically.

To be clear, a scheme is the bit before the domain name, like http:, so you could make your app the handler for urls that start myapp: for example. Obviously no real URLs start with myapp: except for ones that you've designed specifically to be used with your app - that's the whole point.

Unfortunately these URLs will only work with your app, they can't be opened in Safari if your app isn't installed. iTunes, Google maps, Youtube, etc all work that way on iPhone because Apple has hard-coded them as special cases, but they don't make this mechanism available to third party apps.

To register a custom scheme for your app, follow this tutorial: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

What you may be able to do instead is set up a regular web page which uses javascript to detect the user agent of the device and if it's an iPhone redirect to the app's custom scheme url automatically using document.location = 'myapp:...'. I'm not sure what happens if you try to redirect to a custom url scheme if the app's not installed though. It may do nothing, which would be ideal for you, or it may throw up an error or go to a blank page in which case you'd be better off popping up a message like "click here to launch the app or click here to download it from the app store", which is what most sites seem to do.